# How to solve the org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, php, android, json

I'm currently developing a register login application. I'm facing this problem and i can't find any solution that can solve the problem. Anyone have any solution about this? Help will be greatly appreciated.

RegisterActivity.java

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
AlertDialog.Builder builder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
    final EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    final EditText etUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
    final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    final EditText etAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
    final EditText etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    final Button bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);

    bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final String name = etName.getText().toString();
            final String username = etUserName.getText().toString();
            final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
            final int age = Integer.parseInt(etAge.getText().toString());
            final String email = etEmail.getText().toString();

            if (name.equals("") || username.equals("") || password.equals("") || age == 0 || email.equals("")) {
                builder.setTitle("Something Went Wrong");
                builder.setMessage("Please fill in all the fileds").setPositiveButton("OK", null).create().show();

            } else {

                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                            if (success) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Registration Failed").setNegativeButton("Retry", null).create().show();

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }


                };
                RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, username, password, age, email, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
                queue.add(registerRequest);


            }
        }

    });
}
```

Register.php

```
   <?php

    $servername = "mysql6.000webhost.com";
    $username = "a5124128_user";
    $password = "paddwoed4896";
    $dbname = "a5124128_account";


    $con =  mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die(mysql_error());

    $db_selected = mysql_selectdb($con, $dbname);

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $age = $_POST["age"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (name, username, password, age, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sssis", $name, $username, $password, $age, $email);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $response = array();;
    $response["success"] = true;  

    echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

The following is the logcat

```
    09-25 15:41:50.697 17259-17259/com.example.chang.e_ktm W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
09-25 15:41:50.698 17259-17259/com.example.chang.e_ktm W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
09-25 15:41:50.698 17259-17259/com.example.chang.e_ktm W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
09-25 15:41:50.698 17259-17259/com.example.chang.e_ktm W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
09-25 15:41:50.698 17259-17259/com.example.chang.e_ktm W/System.err:     at com.example.chang.e_ktm.RegisterActivity$1$1.onResponse(RegisterActivity.java:78)
09-25 15:41:50.698 17259-17259/com.example.chang.e_ktm W/System.err:     at com.example.chang.e_ktm.RegisterActivity$1$1.onResponse(RegisterActivity.java:73)
09-25 15:41:50.699 17259-17259/com.example.chang.e_ktm W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:67)
09-25 15:41:50.699 17259-17259/com.example.chang.e_ktm W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
09-25 15:41:50.699 17259-17259/com.example.chang.e_ktm W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
09-25 15:41:50.699 17259-17259/com.example.chang.e_ktm W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
09-25 15:41:50.699 17259-17259/com.example.chang.e_ktm W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
09-25 15:41:50.699 17259-17259/com.example.chang.e_ktm W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:210)
09-25 15:41:50.699 17259-17259/com.example.chang.e_ktm W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5830)
09-25 15:41:50.699 17259-17259/com.example.chang.e_ktm W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-25 15:41:50.699 17259-17259/com.example.chang.e_ktm W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-25 15:41:50.699 17259-17259/com.example.chang.e_ktm W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1113)
09-25 15:41:50.699 17259-17259/com.example.chang.e_ktm W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:879)
```

Can someone please help me about this problem? The problem seems like occur on the response.listener

POSTMAN result

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dBM6.png

Comment: Can you update the question with the JSON response attached?

Comment: @fluffyBatman What do you mean with the JSONreponse attached? Where can I find it?

Comment: What is the value of the response of `public void onResponse(String response)`?

Comment: @fluffyBatman Sorry to say that, actually i'm new to android...I was following the video tutorial from youtube. I do not know what is the value of response though...Can you tell me further about that? How can I know what is the value of it? Thanks in advance

Comment: you can add a Breakpoint at the line 'JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);' and see debug your application

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting proper response from your `php api`. So check that `api` once using any `REST client` like postman.

Comment: Then what to do after checking the api?

Comment: @loneranger can your send me the json response which you are getting from your api

Comment: how to send it to you?

Comment: @loneranger post it in your question

Comment: I added into my question..Is that the one you were saying?

Comment: @loneranger added Can you check once

Answer (score 0):

The "Value <!DOCTYPE" seems to indicate you are not receiving a JSON payload, but a [HTML one](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp). Which means that the problem may stay on your server side, crashing before the `echo json_encode($response);` and generating an error page (highly probable a '500 server error').

To confirm, try sending the same payload by accessing the URL from a browser (try a GET)  - see what response comes back.

Or just start debugging your PHP script set some breakpoints inside and then trigger the request from the clients side (you setup your PHP debugging into your IDE, haven't you?).

Comment: i didn't get you...what do you mean?

Comment: (Sorry, the MD eat my &lt; in "Value <!DOCTYPE"). What I mean is: probably you are receiving a HTML page instead of a json payload. This can happen if PHP reaches an error, in which case it will output the "code 500 error page", containing diagnosis info; meant to be read by humans, it is certainly something that a json parser won't expect. The rest are suggestions on how to check this hypothesis.